# Is there any way that I can specify one of two commands if they have the same name in windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, chocolatey

Specifically I have a conflict with using cup parser generator and chocolatey. Both have a command "cup" with chocolatey's "cup" meaning choco upgrade.
Is there any way I can specify which command the command line should use? Or replace one command with a different word?

Comment: Run `where.exe cup` to find the fully-qualified path. This will list all  "cup" + ext files found in `PATH`, where the extensions are taken from the `PATHEXT` environment variable. Use the full path in a shell shortcut (.LNK) that's stored in a common directory for scripts and shortcuts that's set in the `PATH` environment variable. Use an empty "start in" directory in the shortcut to inherit the shell's current directory. Add ".LNK" to `PATHEXT` to run shortcuts from the command line without having to type the ".lnk" file extension.

Comment: How do I create a .LNK shortcut? Do I have to create this common directory? And I am pretty lost on this part " Use an empty "start in" directory in the shortcut to inherit the shell's current directory."

Comment: Creating a shortcut using the Windows shell and modifying environment variables are common tasks. You can find many tutorials. Create a directory for scripts and shortcuts to programs in your profile directory. Name it whatever you want, e.g. "Scripts". When you create a shortcut to a file in this directory, you'll see a "start in" field; leave this blank. Add the full path to this directory to your per-user `PATH`, and add ".LNK" to `PATHEXT`. Note that these variables are delimited by semicolon, and they should contain no double or single quote characters, even if a path contains spaces.